# Custom Fields Not Showing (ACF not installed)

Tags: custom-field, post-meta

Custom Fields not showing on edit page. When I look at Screen Options it doesn't even show up.
[image: Picture of screen options]

I've looked around for a while and saw that people who had the Advanced Custom Fields ran into the same issue. However, I do not have that plugin installed and I haven't found any other help online.

Solution:
The Karma theme removes the custom fields meta box in the file Karma/framework/site-options-functions.php. If you go to Appearance -> Site Options you'll be able to show the hidden meta boxes.

Comment: What post type are you on?

Comment: @NightHawk it's a page

Comment: Maybe one your plugins or your theme has a function (`remove_meta_box`) that disables / removes the custom fields metabox?

Comment: @Eli I can confirm that it should natively be there for pages, so it could be the theme or a plugin that's removing that. You could disable each plugin one at a time to see if it comes back.

Comment: Figured it out, it's the Karma theme